# Задача с массивами,минимальными/максимальнми элементами и индексами

Tags: java, массивы, индексы

пытаюсь решить эту задачу,но у меня как в сказке,срубаю одну голову змею,появляются две другие.
Собственно ,задание вот :
Дано целое число N и последовательность из N целых чисел. Найти сумму элементов, которые стоят между минимальным и максимальным элементом. Если минимальных чисел несколько, минимальное число взять с минимальным индексом. Если максимальных чисел несколько, максимальное число взять с максимальным индексом.
Я не прохожу проверку:10(n)
2 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 4
Должен быть ответ 15,а у меня 9.И я знаю,почему.Но не могу понять,как это сделать.А может и вовсе,то ,что я написал-бред.Помогите,люди добрые)

```
public class Tak33 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[n];
        int sum = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        int indexOfMax = 0;
        int indexOfMin = 0;
        int min, max;
        min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            if (min >= a[i])
                min = a[i];
            if (max <= a[i])
                max = a[i];
            if (a[i] > a[indexOfMax])
                indexOfMax = i;
            else if (a[i] < a[indexOfMin])
                indexOfMin = i;
            if (i == a.length - 1) {
                for (int j = indexOfMin; j <= indexOfMax; j++) {
                    if (a[j] != min && a[j] != max)
                        sum += a[j];
                }
            }
        }
        if(sum == 0) {
            for (int m = indexOfMax; m <= indexOfMin; m++) {
                if (a[m] != min && a[m] != max) {
                    sum += a[m];
                }
            }
        }
            if (max == min) {
                sum = n * max-(2*min);
            }System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "И я знаю,почему." - нам скажете?

Comment: Я пробовал менять в алгоритме нахождения индексов знак > на >= и тогда вроде норм всё)
Но я понимаю,что нужно сделать как-то,что бы программа понимала,что если в массиве одинаковые числа,то индексируем с самого первого до самого последнего,исключая максимум и минимум.

Comment: В целом,я возможно и несу чушь,просто я правда,уже второй день бьюсь над задачей,сори)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i] = scanner.nextInt();
  if (a[i] >= a[indexOfMax])
    indexOfMax = i;
  else if (a[i] < a[indexOfMin])
    indexOfMin = i;
}
for (int m = Math.min(indexOfMax, indexOfMin) + 1; m < Math.max(indexOfMax, indexOfMin); m++) {
  sum += a[m];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,заработало)

Comment: @ПавелКулагин Пожалуйста. "Галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Очень радует тот факт,что сам главный разработчик  небезызвестной компании , помогает таким как я.
Круто.Ещё раз спасибо)